# Clueless about how to change an item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and am adding to this array a JavaScript object.

```
var channels = [];
var channel = {
    id: data.channels[i].id,
    name: data.channels[i].name,
    head_name: groups[data.channels[i].group-1],
    show_title: show_group_title             // var show_group_title = false;
}
channels.push(channel);
```

Now I want to change the show_title of the first array from **false** to **true**. How I could do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want

```
channels[0].show_title = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what behavior do you expect... Do you need something like this?

```
var channel = {
    id: data.channels[i].id,
    name: data.channels[i].name,
    head_name: groups[data.channels[i].group-1],
    show_title: function() { return groups_show_title[data.channels[i].group-1]; }
    // or just
    // show_title: groups_show_title[data.channels[i].group-1]
}
```

This code needs an additional array.